# how to clear the file content cache in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, caching

i have removed code still executing.
i'm under Linux Mint and use VScode for a ruby program.
i already tried to delete the File Content Cache, using
(ctrl + shift + P) and typed "Clear Editor History" then Enter, but the deleted code still executes.
i need a sloution

Comment: i tried deleting non essential plugins, removing the code file, then removing/reinstalling VSCode was my solution.